# Why can the \$I_c\$ be written as \$\frac{V_{CC}-5V}{R1+R3}\$?

Tags: bjt, homework

Why is it \$I_C=\frac{V_{cc}-5V}{R1+R3}\$ and not \$I_C=\frac{V_{cc}-5V}{R1}\$?
I am a little bit confused with it, can anyone tell me the reason?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fP1sr7.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things. First, the current on its way down from \$V_{CC}\$ to ground splits into two paths at the collector, but merges again at the emitter:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhG49x.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Due to KCL, this means that the currents through R1 and R3 are equal, \$I_C\$.

<sub>It's worth noting that If anything else is connected the base, and is sinking/sourcing *non-zero* \$I_3\$, this condition is no longer true, and currents through R1 and R3 would no longer be equal.</sub>

Second, by KVL we can see that

$$ V_1 + V_2 + V_3 = V_{CC} $$

Ohm's law:

$$
\begin{aligned}
V_1 &= I_CR_1 \\ \\
V_3 &= I_CR_3 \\ \\
\end{aligned}
$$

Combining all those:

$$
\begin{aligned}
I_CR_1 + 5V + I_CR_3 &= V_{CC} \\ \\
I_C(R_1 + R_3) &= V_{CC} - 5V \\ \\
I_C &= \frac{V_{CC} - 5V}{R_1 + R_3} \\ \\
\end{aligned}
$$

Also, and I can't stress this enough, it means that \$I_C\$ is *not* collector current here. It's badly mislabelled, collector current in this schematic is \$I_X\$.

Comment: YES!you are right,i made a mistake in defining the $I_C$

Answer (score 3):

\$I_C\$, which (despite the name) consists of the transistor collector current plus the base current, flows through **both** R1 and R3, exactly the same current.

The total  voltage across R1 and R3 is \$5V-V_{CE}\$, so \$I_C = \frac{5V-V_{CE}}{R_1+R_3}\$

Maybe the issue is that \$V_{CE}\$ (as the nomenclature indicates) is measured from the transistor **collector** to the **emitter** (and not to ground).

Answer (score 2):

After subtracting 5 volts (the value of BJT CE voltage) from \$V_{CC}\$,  the remaining voltage is shared across R1 and R3. Because R1 and R3 share the same current, that current has to be: -

$$\dfrac{V_{CC}-5}{R_1+R_3}$$

Maybe you are not recognizing that emitter current and collector current are identical in this particular circuit?

Comment: +1 I think this is the *simple and direct* answer to the question. One is told there's 5 V across the BJT. Which leaves the rest for the two resistors.

Answer (score 1):

With a simple KVL you can write

$$
\mathrm{V_{CC}=V_{R1}+V_{CE}+V_{R3}}
$$

where V<sub>R1</sub> and V<sub>R3</sub> are the drops across R1 and R3, respectively.

The drop across R1 is determined by the sum of the collector and the base current. Because, as you can see, current flowing through R1 comes down and, at the R2-R1 junction (BJT's collector node), splits into base and collector currents. We can neglect the base current here as it's something like one hundredth (generally) of the collector current. So

$$
\mathrm{V_{R1}=(I_C+I_B) \ R1\approx I_C \ R1}
$$

Likewise, the drop across R3 is determined by the emitter current, which is equal to the sum of the collector and the base currents. We can do the same assumption as above and use the collector current instead:

$$
\mathrm{V_{R3}=I_E \ R3 = (I_C+I_B) \ R3\approx I_C \ R3}
$$

Putting all together, we have

$$
\mathrm{V_{CC}=V_{R1}+V_{CE}+V_{R3}=I_C \ R1+V_{CE}+I_C \ R3 \\
\Rightarrow I_C=\frac{V_{CC}-V_{CE}}{R1+R3} \ \ \ \ ; V_{CE}=5V \\
\Rightarrow I_C=\frac{V_{CC}-5}{R1+R3}}
$$

Also it's worth noting that the voltage V<sub>CE</sub> is given as the voltage across collector and emitter of BJT, **not** across collector and ground. If it was given as the latter then the collector current would be equal to the second equation in your question.

NOTE: Here I deliberately used I<sub>C</sub> as the BJT's collector current, instead of that flowing through R3 as shown in the OP's schematic.

Comment: ,May I know which tool you are using for writing equations.

Comment: @Hari There's no tool. It's just that EE.SE supports MathJax. You can find the tutorial somewhere in Stackoverflow. Just google it.